# Multi-select showing null value in primeng on assigning value programmatically in typescript

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using angular 2 and primeng to show a multiselect dropdown.

```
  <div class="ui-g-9">
    <p-multiSelect [options]="groupsDropDown"  [(ngModel)]="selectedGroups" [style]="{'width':'50%'}">
    </p-multiSelect>
     </div>
```

Now in typescript on a function call am reassigning the value.

```
editEmail(publishingGroup) {
    this.selectedGroups = publishingGroup.groups;
}
```

On this the Multiselect dropdown label shows the selected value but the option remains unchecked as shown in the picture.
[image]

Also the label value gets null on selection of another option as shown below,here the "developer" is turned as null somehow.

[image]

Comment: Random square bracket on your style attribute shouldn't cause an issue but worth fixing to avoid confusion.  Sounds like you are replacing an array where the component might expect modifications to the existing object but would need to dig into the source code and step through the component to see what it's doing with the supplied ngModel

Answer (score 1):

Found the reason for the error,since I was using primeng version 2 and I was binding the value in the ngModel with an object {label:somelabel,value:somevalue}
it showed the null error,The error was removed when I binded value to the ngmodel with only value object, like {value : somevalue}.

Comment: This answer saved me mate. I had no clue why my model is not displaying as selected on binding the SelectItem object. Apparently I only had to bind the value part of it.